# adding objects to array leads to duplicates

Tags: javascript

I know its fundamental but got stuck. I'm trying to add objects into an array:

Html

```
<p>
  <label>
    <input type="text" name="test1" id="test1" />
  </label>
</p>
<p>
  <label>
    <input type="text" name="test2" id="test2" />
  </label>
</p>
```

Script

```
var res = {};
  var array_res = [];
function init(){
    x= $('#test1').val();   
    res['x'] = x;
    y= $('#test2').val();
    res['y'] = y;       

    array_res.push(res);

    return array_res
}
 $('#btn').click(function(){
 init();
 console.log(array_res);
  });
```

When first adding x=1 and y=2 i get at console:

```
[Object { x="1",  y="2"}]
```

Next i try to insert x=3 and y=4 and i get:

```
 [Object { x="3",  y="4"}, Object { x="3",  y="4"}]
```

instead of

```
 [Object { x="1",  y="2"}, Object { x="3",  y="4"}]
```

Why is that? I smell its an  object instance issue but can't figure out what to do. Thanks in advance

Comment: Don't use global vars. Move the `var res = {}` into the `init` function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you add an object to an array, you're not adding the object *itself*, but instead a reference to it.  Updating the object itself will also be reflected in the array because the array simply "points" to the object.  Because your `res` object is declared in the global scope, the second call to `init()` will clobber the previous values which are being pointed to in `array_res`.

Consider this short demo: https://jsfiddle.net/35uu7bje/

```
var obj = {a: 5, b: 10};
var arr = [];

arr.push(obj);
console.log("Object in array before update");
console.log(arr[0]);
// Displays {a: 5, b: 10}

obj.a = 25;
console.log("Object in array after update");
console.log(arr[0]);
// Displays {a: 25, b: 10}
```

To fix this, you should declare `res` in the function scope so each new call creates a new object instead of recycling an old one:

```
// Do NOT declare res here
// Doing so will cause every entry in array_res to point to one instance of this object
// var res = {};
var array_res = [];

function init(){
    // Declare it here so each call creates a new res object
    var res = {};
```

It should also be noted that because objects are passed *by reference*, passing an object as a parameter to a function allows for the original object to be modified:

```
var obj = {a: 5, b: 10};

function f( some_obj ) {
    some_obj.a = 25;
}

console.log(obj); // {a: 5, b: 10}
f(obj);
console.log(obj); // {a: 25, b: 10}
```

Comment: Best answer, in details.

Comment: @nik - This *by reference* behavior also applies when passing objects to functions.  I made an edit to include a demo.

Answer (score 1):

Move `res` variable to `init` function

```js
var array_res = [];

function init() {
   
    var res = {};
    x = $('#test1').val();   
    res['x'] = x;
    y= $('#test2').val();
    res['y'] = y;       

    array_res.push(res);

    return array_res
}

$('#btn').click(function(){
  init();
 
  console.log(array_res);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>
  <label>
    <input type="text" name="test1" id="test1" />
  </label>
</p>

<p>
  <label>
    <input type="text" name="test2" id="test2" />
  </label>
</p>

<button id="btn">Add</button>
```